# WebJob Runs Twice per each cron Schedule

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob with the following cron

```
{"schedule": "0 0 * * * *"}
```

My logging and the logs from Kudu {site...}/azurejobs/#/jobs/triggered/{jobName} shows 2 successive entries running every hour within a minute of each other. The App Service plan is set to single instance.

How can I determine why I get 2 executions per scheduled event?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that if you set up the Azure Scheduler *in addition* to the Kudu CRON file, they will each fire and cause a double invocation.

Any chance that you set up a schedule using VS? That would set up the Azure Scheduler. If so, you can delete the unwanted scheduler Job Collection.

Also, using Kudu Console, go under D:\home\data\jobs\triggered{jobname} and look at `job_scheduler.log`. That should only account for the Kudu cron scheduler.

Comment: I originally started with Scheduler from VS, I deleted the Schedule resource added the settings.job, tweaked webjob-publish-settings to  "runMode": "OnDemand". I did go and look and see that my Schedule resource had been recreated. I deleted it again redeployed and seems Schedule it was not recreated this time.....working ok now.

Comment: I don't know what recreated it, but that was clearly the reason for the duplication.

Comment: What is the actual trigger to make a Schedule be created for the WebJob, I would assume the 'runMode = Scheduled' setting in the publish file?

Comment: I actually do see 2 entries per hour in the '\triggered\{jobname}' folder.